# Need to webscrape from a content stream

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to webscrape from [yahoo stock market news](https://finance.yahoo.com/topic/stock-market-news) and get the headers, the news description, and the time. Unfortunately, when using BeautifulSoup, I can only get the first 10 titles. I think this is because the page updates as you scroll. Does anyone know how to "scroll" the page a bit. I'm trying to get articles for an entire day at a time (~100 articles).

Heres my current code:

```
page = result.content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
main = soup.find(id = 'Main')
cells = main.find_all(class_ = 'js-stream-content Pos(r)')
results = []
print(len(cells))
for cell in cells:
  title = cell.find('a')
  print(title.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at pyautogui for simulating scrolling.

[Pyautogui Scrolling](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-scrolling)